# obtener frases con la API de wikote

Tags: javascript, api

estuve consultando la API de Wikote y obtuve todos los datos que necesitaba a traves de las etiquetas `td` que me traía el JSON pero al existir alguna frase sin imagen los indices cambian y por lo tanto me da un error.

```js
var span = function (data) {
            frase=data['parse']['text']['*'];
            document.getElementById('seoo').innerHTML = frase;
            var tabla = document.getElementsByTagName("td");    
            document.getElementById('imagen').innerHTML = tabla[0].innerHTML;           
            document.getElementById('frase').innerHTML = tabla[2].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>?/g, '');
            document.getElementById('autor').innerHTML = tabla[4].innerHTML;            
            img = (document.getElementById("imagen")).getElementsByTagName("img");
            
            var imagen = img.currentSrc;
            var cita = tabla[2].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>?/g, '');
            var autor = ((document.getElementById('autor')).getElementsByTagName("a"))[0].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('autor').innerHTML = autor;
        
        };

        var frase = function () {

            var titulo='{{Plantilla:Frase-jueves}}';
            var titulo2='{{Plantilla:Portada/temporal/Cita_del_día}}';
            
            
            url = 'http://es.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text='+titulo+'&format=json&callback=span';
            var elem = document.createElement('script');
            elem.setAttribute('src', url);
            elem.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(elem);
        };
```

```html
<body onload="frase();">
<span id="seoo"></span><br><br>
    <span id="imagen"></span><br>
    <span id="frase"></span><br>
    <span id="autor"></span>    
</body>
```

En el JS en la url; si cambio a titulo2 no me muestra ninguna información porque esa frase no contiene la etiqueta td de la imagen. Necesito obtener únicamente el src de la imagen, la frase y el autor.

Comment: ¿Podría revisar el snippet? No muestra ningún resultado y en la consola de las herramientas de desarrollo aparece un error de Mixed Content.

Comment: Ya lo actualicé, el primero es la tabla que me da el JSON de Wikote lo otro es lo que yo logro extraer.